# Что лучше для организации http запросов Volley или Retrofit?

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, retrofit, android-volley

Я только начал изучать принципы построения клиент-серверных приложений для андроид, но я насколько понял из прочитанного и увиденного что мне нужно сделать запросы к бд на сервере через какую-то из библиотек Volley или Retrofit. Но проблема в том что я не знаю о преимуществах и недостатках этих библиотек. Так же буду рад любым советам по построению клиент-серверного приложения так как я в этом полный ноль))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Retrofit** предназначен для получения и парсинга JSON (или других структурированных данных, таких как XML) из некоторой веб-службы,
или отправки этих данных. Также Retrofit упрощает работу с HTTP-операциями и фоновыми потоками. Обычно нужно использовать Retrofit, если вы общаетесь с веб-сервисом. Если вам нужна загрузка изображений, следует использовать библиотеку Picasso. Для прочих HTTP-операций можно использовать OkHTTP.

**Volley** - детище Google, используется в приложении Play Store и многих других приложениях Google. Volley может рассматриваться как совокупность Retrofit + Picasso, и может использоваться для замены нескольких библиотек. Недостаток этой библиотеки - не очень много документации (в основном это I|O видео и [раздел на оф. сайте android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)).

Для получения более полной картины по этому вопросу могут помочь следующие ссылки:

[Volley vs Retrofit. Описание библиотек REST API](https://ziginsider.github.io/Volley-vs-Retrofit/).

[Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley)